# Passar valor para janela modal, recuperar o dado e reutiliza-lo

Tags: php, javascript, twitter-bootstrap

Boa tarde a todos.
Pessoal, possuo a seguinte dificuldade:
Possuo a seguinte tela:

[image: 01.png]

Ao clicar no botão em destaque(Editar), abre-se essa janela modal, onde passo pra ela o ID da solicitação, e a data, como mostra a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Minha dificuldade consiste em reutilizar as informações que passei. Como podem ver, consegui passar essas informações e recupera-las via `javaScript`, só que quando submeto meu formulário, ou tento capturar o valor do campo pelo id, me retorna `null`.

Passei as informações da seguinte forma:

Botão que chama o modal, e passo a informação através do atributo `data-id='$xid|$dataexibir'`

```
<a type='button' href='#editar' class='btn btn-primary espacos' data-toggle='modal' data-target='.editar' data-id='$xid|$dataexibir' id='btnEditar' >
```

Campo que recebe a informação na janela modal:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="meuid" id="meuid" disabled="true">
```

Função javascript que usei para passar os dados:

```
   $(document).on("click", "#btnEditar", function () {
        var info = $(this).attr('data-id');
        var str = info.split('|');
        var meuid = str[0];
        var minhadata = str[1];
        $(".modal-body #meuid").val(meuid);
        $(".modal-body #minhadata").val(minhadata);
    });
```

Como podem ver na segunda imagem, eu tento recuperar esse id para fazer um select e preencher essa tabela em baixo com as informações já contidas para esse id, e não consigo, como também não consigo recuperar ou submeter através do form.
Fico no aguardo por alguma ajuda, e desde já agradeço a atenção.
Obrigado!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você não consegue capturar os dados porque definiu neles o atributo `disabled` como `true`. Fazendo isso, esse campos são ignorados. É como se eles não existissem.

Para resolver seu problema, remova o atributo disabled e invés disso, para não perder o efeito desejado, adicione a classe `disabled` do Bootstrap.

```
<input type="text" class="disabled" id="input1" name="input1">
```

Espero ter contribuido.

@Edit

Para as futuras pessoas que estiverem com esse problema, usem o `readonly`

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="input1" name="input1" readonly"
```

Parece ser a maneira mais correta de conseguir este efeito.

Comment: Sim, contribuiu. Na verdade, minutos depois de postar a pergunta percebi isso, e ao invés da classe do Bootstrap, adicionei um atributo chamado `readonly="readdonly"`, e resolveu. Muito obrigado @Clayderson Ferreira pela atenção e ajuda! :)